# How to find index of first set bit

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

Is there bitwise solution to find the index of first set bit in mask with only one bit set?
e.g. for 8 it would be 3, for 16 => 4 and so on. No loops plz.
The best solution I can come up with is to createa  map of bit to index.

Comment: `No loops plz` - I love seeing that kind of stipulation. Why do you dislike loops?

Comment: With loops it's trivial)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function firstBit(x) {
    return Math.floor(
        Math.log(x | 0) / Math.log(2)
    ) + 1;
}
i=4; console.log(i.toString(2), firstBit(i)); // 100 3
i=7; console.log(i.toString(2), firstBit(i)); // 111 3
i=8; console.log(i.toString(2), firstBit(i)); // 1000 4
```

Comment: This is assuming `x.toString(2).length` won't float your boat

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!)
I guess Math.floor is used only for cases when multiple bits are set?

Comment: Yep. I added `1` to them so it matched with _length_, if you dont want that you can remove it, and `firstBit(0)` is `-Infinity` (because it doesn't have one!). The `x | 0` casts `x` to a _32-bit integer_

Comment: Math.floor(value)+1 can be replaced by (value | 0)+1

Comment: @DenisNarushevich Yep, it would change edge cases though (`0`). Just use whatever suits your needs!

Answer (score 3):

For posterity, ES6 introduced `Math.log2` (and also `log10`) which does exactly that:

```
Math.log2(8) === 3
```

As a reminder, `logA(x)` is `logB(x) / logB(A)` for any `A` and `B`

Comment: `Math.floor(Math.log2(n))` works for any number.